# how to call the same function 3 times in C?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how to get a function (in my case a smiley face i made) to call itself 3 times using recursion. My teacher was not thorough in his teaching of it, and I do not know what to put in the code to make the function repeat via this method. My code looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("  * * * *\n");
    printf("*          *\n");
    printf("    .    .\n");
    printf("*          *\n");
    printf("*    \\_/   *\n");
    printf("*          *\n");
    printf("  * * * *\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not recursion! Just a for-loop

Comment: @pazqo he asked for recursion though.

Answer (score 10):

For recursion you need two things:

1. A solution where the function calls itself but with a "simpler" version of the problem
2. A base case where no recursion occurs

The usual example is `factorial`. `n!` is `n * (n - 1)!` for all numbers greater than 0 (that's the first part) and [`0!` is defined as 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25336/428865) (that's the second part).

```
int factorial(int n) 
{
    assert(n >= 0); // Otherwise, trouble!
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

So to print your face three times, first print it twice and then print it again. To generalise, for n > 0, print your face n - 1 times and then print it again. And for n = 0, do nothing.

So your recursive function should take a parameter `n` that tells it how many times to print the face. If `n` is greater than 0, it should recursively call itself to print the face `n - 1` times and then print the face again.

The exact code, I'll leave to you.

Comment: Wish I could give more than +1 for teaching a man to fish.  If he takes the time to understand your answer, he'll understand a lot more about functions and recursion.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Thanks.

Comment: Corner: `factorial(0)` is [well defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25333/why-does-0-1)  Suggest `assert(n >= 0); if (n <= 1) ...`

Comment: @chux I thought about that when I first wrote the answer and chose not to mention it, but on balance and with your link, I think it works better, especially as it more accurately reflects my description of how to solve the questioner's problem.

Answer (score 2):

This code works. Make sure you ask questions if you do not understand, and make sure you understand the code as this is your curriculum...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void smiley_print(int times_to_call)
{
    printf("  * * * *\n");
    printf("*          *\n");
    printf("    .    .\n");
    printf("*          *\n");
    printf("*    \\_/   *\n");
    printf("*          *\n");
    printf("  * * * *\n");
    getchar();
    if(--times_to_call) smiley_print(times_to_call);
}

int main()
{
    smiley_print(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a recursive function executing `doStuff()` `N` times:

```
void repeatDoStuff(int N)
{
    if (N > 0)
    {
        doStuff();
        repeatDoStuff(N-1);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Y0p4Ol)

Answer (score 1):

> how to call the same function 3 times in C? (using recursion)

Recursion rightly receives a bad reputation when a simple loop would suffice.

Consider the recursive solution below which has a maximum recursive depth of `O(n)`

```
void print_face(int n) {  // recurse
  if (n > 0) {
    printf(A_string_representing_a_face);
    print_face(n-1);
  }
}

// vs.

void print_face(int n) {  // no recursion
  while (n > 0) {
    n--; 
    printf(A_string_representing_a face);
  }
}

//usage
print_face(3);
```

---

Some compilers will identify the pattern as [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)  and emit similar code as the loop.  Other compilers will not see this and incur potentially excessively deep recursion.  [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

**Good recursion:**

1. Detects when no more recursion is needed like `if (n == 0)`
2. Makes for *significantly* smaller tasks.

Consider the recursive solution below which has a maximum recursive depth of `O(log2(n))`.  If `n` was 3 million, instead of a recursive depth of 3 million as above, the depth would be 22.  It is this *significantly* smaller task that makes for a good recursion solution - when a simply loop does not suffice.

```
void print_face(int n) {  // recurse
  if (n > 0) {
    printf(A_string_representing_a_face);

    n--; 
    print_face(n/2);
    print_face(n - n/2);
  }
}
```